# DELETE from LIMIT 1 error

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sqlite

i have problem with LIMIT 1 in SQLite, my query without LIMIT 1  works fine, but sometimes removes every duplicate elements. I'd like to delete 1 row.

this works:

```
myDataBase.execSQL("DELETE FROM praca
 WHERE pomieszczenie_id="+pomieszczenieid+" 

AND (praca.usluga_id IN (SELECT usluga_id FROM usluga
     WHERE usluga_nazwa='"+childvalue+"'))
AND (sciana_id IN(SELECT sciana_id from sciana 
    WHERE sciana_nazwa='"+rodzic_nazwa+"'))");
```

this returns Near "LIMIT" syntax error

```
myDataBase.execSQL("DELETE FROM praca
 WHERE pomieszczenie_id="+pomieszczenieid+" 

AND (praca.usluga_id IN (SELECT usluga_id FROM usluga
     WHERE usluga_nazwa='"+childvalue+"'))
AND (sciana_id IN(SELECT sciana_id from sciana 
    WHERE sciana_nazwa='"+rodzic_nazwa+"')) LIMIT 1");
```

How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you may need to enable `SQLITE ENABLE UPDATE DELETE LIMIT` OR a workaround likeTHIS:

```
 delete from tablename where rowid in (
    select rowid from tablename condition LIMIT 1)
```

above query is just an example, replace it with your query and conditions.

Comment: I worked some time with this problem, your syntax works :) Limit 1 missed, thx for help

Answer (score 1):

I think you should to enable **SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT** http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit

You must compile SQLite using NDK, and add parameter to enable SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT

Comment: It seems to be a bit of complicated. It's weird SQLite has no built-in LIMIT method.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead:

```
DELETE FROM praca where pomieszczenie_id in
(
select pomieszczenie_id from praca
 WHERE pomieszczenie_id="+pomieszczenieid+" 

AND (praca.usluga_id IN (SELECT usluga_id FROM usluga
     WHERE usluga_nazwa='"+childvalue+"'))
AND (sciana_id IN(SELECT sciana_id from sciana 
    WHERE sciana_nazwa='"+rodzic_nazwa+"')) LIMIT 1
)
```